# Function for which it is unknown whether it is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Is there any function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ for which at least some values are known but it is unknown whether $f$ is continuous or not?

***Edit:** I am looking for examples from actual research, not functions explicitly constructed for that purpose.*

Comment: Continuous in the known values? Continuous in $\Bbb R$?...

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: It would be extra cool of course if continuity were unknown in the known values, but any real-world example will suffice where continuity is unknown anywhere.

Comment: As every computable (warning!, computable real function is a very nontrivial idea) function is continuous (http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/01/what-does-topology-have-to-do-with.html, http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/all-functions-are-continuous-always/, http://math.andrej.com/2006/03/27/sometimes-all-functions-are-continuous/) you need a well defined uncomputable function.

Answer (score -1):

Let $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=$ the first even number that is not the sum of two primes.

Comment: Understood, though I am actually looking for a "real-world" example, not one that is explicitly constructed for that purpose. Equivalently, let $f(0)=1$ if and only if some open conjecture is true, $0$ otherwise...

Comment: That function is discontinuous regardless of the result. Setting $f(0) = 0$ if such a number does not exist would be okay, though.

Comment: @pew This isn't even right, this might not even be a function at all.